# Cocos2D: Best process to make hd versions of tmx files?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display, tmx

According to a Cocos2D guide a copy of HD tmx files for every SD one you have, adding the indicator "-hd" at the end of the filename. The tilewidth, tileheight, spacing and margin properties all need to be twice as large in the HD verions. Finally, the HD tile atlas needs to have -hd at the end of the filename, and it needs to appear written this way in the HD tmx file.

[http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:how_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3ahow_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d)

I have lots of SD tmx maps that I often make changes to. Is there a process people usually use to make these HD versions automatically? The only thing I can think of is running a script in Xcode's build process, but it sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: It is a nightmare, it's just one reason why I ended up rewriting cocos2d's tilemap renderer for KoboldTouch and Kobold Kit. There weren't even any fully working upscaling scripts/tools out there last time I checked (existing ones were either broken or did not scale everything or not correctly).